# jQuery Smooth Scroll scrolls to wrong target when live (works on test page)

Tags: jquery, scroll, smoothing, targets

I've been searching for a solution without success for quite a while now, maybe someone here might be able to help me! :)

I'm new to jQuery so it's possible that it's something simple I've forgotten, but the scroll works fine when i test the page in my browser, it just doesn't work when I upload the page to my server. As soon as it's live, the links stop working or sometimes scroll an inch or so but not to the right place.

I can't upload all code here, so here's the live page: http://www.carolinaekstrom.se/

The link "om mig" is supposed to stop at the picture of me, "kontakt" at "hör gärna av er!", and "portfolio", well at the portfolio :)

Here's my js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 function filterPath(string) {
return string
.replace(/^\//,'')
.replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/,'')
.replace(/\/$/,'');
}
var locationPath = filterPath(location.pathname);
var scrollElem = scrollableElement('html', 'body');

$('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
var thisPath = filterPath(this.pathname) || locationPath;
if (  locationPath == thisPath
&& (location.hostname == this.hostname || !this.hostname)
&& this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
  var $target = $(this.hash), target = this.hash;
  if (target) {
    var targetOffset = $target.offset().top -60;
    $(this).click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 700, function() {

      });
    });
  }
}
});

// use the first element that is "scrollable"
function scrollableElement(els) {
for (var i = 0, argLength = arguments.length; i <argLength; i++) {
  var el = arguments[i],
      $scrollElement = $(el);
  if ($scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0) {
    return el;
  } else {
    $scrollElement.scrollTop(1);
    var isScrollable = $scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0;
    $scrollElement.scrollTop(0);
    if (isScrollable) {
      return el;
    }
  }
}
return [];
}

});
```

Here's the menu:

```
<div class="menu">
<div id="nav">
 <div id="content2">
     <a href="#screen1"><img style="float:left; max-width:33.416%;"    src="menu_01.png" ></a>
     <img style="float:left; max-width:34.416%;" src="menu_02.png" >
     <a href="#screen2"><img style="float:left; max-width:9.833%;" src="menu_03.png" ></a>
     <a href="#screen3"><img style="float:left; max-width:9.6%;" src="menu_05.jpg" ></a>
     <a href="#screen4"><img style="float:left; max-width:11.416%;" src="menu_04.png" ></a>
 </div>
```

Here's my "pages":

```
<div id="pagewrap1">
<a id="screen1"></a>
<a id="pad1"></a>
<a id="mobile1"></a>
<div id="content">
<div id="box1"><img src="carocontent.png" /></div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="pagewrap2">
<a id="screen2"></a>
<a id="pad2"></a>
<a id="mobile2"></a>
<div id="content">
<div id="box2"><img src="jag.jpg" />


 </div>
 </div>
 </div>




<div id="pagewrap3">
<a id="screen3"></a>
<a id="pad3"></a>
<a id="mobile3"></a>
<div id="content">
<div id="box3">

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<div class="text"><div align="center"><b>HÖR GÄRNA AV ER!</b></div></div>
<div class="between"><img src="between.png" /></div>
<div id="contactphone" class="between"><img src="between.png" /></div>


 <div id="contactweb">
  <a href="tel:+46768727892"><img style="max-width:8%;" src="contact_01.png" /></a>
  <a href="mailto:carolina_ekstrom@hotmail.com"><img style="max-width:8%;" src="contact_02.png" /></a>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/carolina.ekstrom.395" target="_blank"><img style="max-width:8%;" src="contact_03.png" /></a>
   </div>


   </div>

   </div>
   </div>
    </div>
```

I'll be very grateful for your help! :)

Comment: what version of jquery you are using???

Comment: eh, I just borrowed the script from here: http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/improved-animated-scrolling-script-for-same-page-links

Comment: Is it an old version?

Comment: did you include jquery.js script file in your page like this
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: yes i have. I mean it works perfectly when i test it in all browsers, so i can't see why it wouldn't work live!

Comment: See what I suggest is try to keep a local copy of that jquery.js and also refer the cdn copy only if its available. There is a method to do that. So what happens is if application fails to load jquery from cdn it will load it from local. If jquery is not loaded then nothing will work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it isn't working properly is that the images are not yet fully loaded when `document ready` event fires. As a note document ready is when the DOM/html is ready for JS to execute however it does not guarantee the resources are loaded.

As a result the `targetOffset` that you initially had calculated is invalid after all the images are loaded.

I would recommend following a delegation pattern like this (which would require some refactoring on your part): http://jsfiddle.net/peterdotjs/tao135x9/19/

```
$('body').on('click', 'nav a', function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($this.attr('href')).offset().top - navHeight 
    },700);
});
```

In my example, the `targetOffset` is calculated on the fly of where to scroll.

As a quick fix if you change your code to run on the [`window.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event it should work as well.

The `window.load` event fires when all resources are loaded - so you can assume that the calculations will be accurate.

I'm not sure why you are using "screen1", "screen2", etc. rather than using an `id` that references the place you want to scroll to typically you would match the `href` id attribute or similar in the nav to the `id` of the element scrolled to.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I changed it to run on window.load and it works fine, thank you so much! :)